# How to get price from Amazon website by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to get the price from the Amazon website.

How can I take the price number?

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Development\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MacBook-16-Inch-Storage-2-6GHz/dp/B08CZT64VP/ref=sr_1_4?crid=2T5BGI71K1C8W&keywords=macbook&qid=1689176236&sprefix=macboo%2Caps%2C357&sr=8-4")

price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-offscreen").get_attribute("aria-hidden")

print(price)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#output: None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple tags with the same class, due to which you may not be able to get the tag that you need. Also you were trying to get an attribute which the element doesn't even have.

Therefore change line

```
price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-offscreen").get_attribute("aria-hidden")
```

to

```
price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.a-price.a-text-price.a-size-medium span.a-offscreen").get_attribute("innerText")
```

Output:

```
$849.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program returns None because the `find_element()` returns the first span (with the a-offscreen class), that does not have an aria-label; then by default if one was not found `get_attribute("aria-label")` returns None. If you want to find the price text use the `.text` attribute of the span object, eg `price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-offscreen").text`

You may refer to https://pythonexamples.org/python-selenium-find-element-by-css-selector/

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text ***$845.69*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MacBook-16-Inch-Storage-2-6GHz/dp/B08CZT64VP/ref=sr_1_4?crid=2T5BGI71K1C8W&keywords=macbook&qid=1689176236&sprefix=macboo%2Caps%2C357&sr=8-4")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#apex_desktop div#corePrice_desktop table.a-lineitem span.apexPriceToPay[data-a-color='price']"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  $845.69
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)